# Stereochemistry of hydrogenation with Raney nickel

Tags: reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, catalysis

If I react the following with Raney nickel and $\ce{H2}$,

$\hspace{65 mm}$[image: alkene]

then I am getting a meso compound, as the $\ce{H-}$ anion will have anti addition, right? One $\ce{H}$ will attack on right $\ce{C}$ from bottom and the other on the left $\ce{C}$ from the top. That makes it a meso. But in the book it says, there is racemization. How?

Comment: check edit @bon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hydrogenation of alkenes using heterogenous catalysts such as Raney nickel is *syn*-stereospecific; i.e. both hydrogen atoms are added to the same face of the double bond.

Therefore, the hydrogenation of (2​*E*)-(2,3-<sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>)but-2-ene yields 
(2​*R*,3​*R*)-(2,3-<sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>)butane and
(2​*S*,3​*S*)-(2,3-<sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>)butane.

[image: hydrogenation]

Answer (score 1):

Good old paper drawing has blindsided you. Think of the $\ce{H2}$ as adding on top of the molecule as you have drawn it on paper. Not all the molecules know that they are supposed to land "right-side" up.

[image: right sideup drawing]

Some will land up side down.

[image: right sideup drawing]

You get stereoisomers when there are four different groups bonded to a single carbon atom. Such a mixture will effect polarized light. One configuration will twist the polarized light positive and the other negative. An equal mixture of such stereoisomers is a racemic mixture and is optically inactive.

Right-side up you get (H)(D)(CH3) going clockwise looking down the C-C axis that was the C=C double bond. Upside-down you get (H)(CH3)(D) going clockwise.

Comment: sorry, didnt understand what you mean by (H)(CH3)(D) going clockwise

Comment: so, is my book correct ?

Comment: Yes. Edited my answer to make that point more clearly.